# Vue and JSONPlaceholder application

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I have put together this small application that uses the **[JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) API** and Vue.js.

The application crosses users and posts and displays the *posts by user* (author):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    base_url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
    uid: 1,
    currentUser: null,
    userData: null,
    users: [],
    posts: []
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActiveUser(user) {
      this.uid = user.id;
    },
    getUsers() {
      axios
        .get(`${this.base_url}/users`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
    getCurrentUser() {
      axios
        .get(`${this.base_url}/users/${this.uid}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.currentUser = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
    getPosts() {
      axios
        .get(`${this.base_url}/posts?userId=${this.uid}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.getCurrentUser();
    this.getPosts();
  },
  watch: {
    currentUser() {
      this.getCurrentUser();
    },
    posts() {
      this.getPosts();
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize(value) {
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    },
    titlecase(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
      });
    },
    lowercase(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.post-grid {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.post-title {
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

.short-desc {
  text-align: justify;
}


/* User Info */

.table.user-info {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table.user-info>tbody>tr:first-child>td {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.table.user-info td {
  padding: 6px !important;
}

.table.user-info tr td:first-child {
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 32% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="#">
      <img src="https://www.pngrepo.com/png/303293/180/bootstrap-4-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-md-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-md  w-100">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-md collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Dropdown -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Authors</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" v-if="users">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" @click="toggleActiveUser(user)">{{user.name}}</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="h4 mt-3">Posts by {{currentUser?.name}}</h1>

    <div v-if="currentUser != null">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
      More about this author
    </button>
    </div>

    <div class="row post-grid" v-if="posts">
      <div class="col-sm-6 post" v-for="post in posts">
        <div class="post-container">
          <h2 class="display-4 post-title">{{post.title | titlecase}}</h2>
          <div class="short-desc">
            {{post.body | capitalize}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="currentUser != null" class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{currentUser?.name}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table user-info">
            <tr>
              <td>Lives in</td>
              <td>{{currentUser?.address.city}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Address</td>
              <td>{{currentUser?.address.street}}, {{currentUser?.address.suite}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zipcode</td>
              <td>{{currentUser?.address.zipcode}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Email</td>
              <td>
                <a href="mailto:{{currentUser?.email | lowercase}}">{{currentUser?.email | lowercase}}</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Questions:

1. Is the code verbose?
2. Does the application leave a lot to be desired in regards to optimization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Is the code verbose?

I would say it is a bit verbose. I first read over the methods to get data via XHR - e.g. users, posts, current user - and noted that they all have similar structure. I considered suggesting that there be one request to get all three types of data to reduce network traffic and allow simplifying the code, but I realize it is an external API being utilized, plus I noticed two of the three methods are called in watchers (see important point related to that in the next section), If that is necessary to have only certain data returned and you had control over the API endpoints then the endpoint could accept a list of data to return.

## 2. Does the application leave a lot to be desired in regards to optimization?

I would say **yes** - check this out: There is the method `getCurrentUser` which will set `currentUser`, and also there is an entry in `watch` for `currentUser` that calls `this.getCurrentUser()` - this typically leads to **an infinite loop**. The owners of the API likely would not like that! If it was my API and I was checking the logs it might look like a Denial of Service attack...

The same is true for `posts`. See this illustrated in the snippet below- notice the console logs that continue unceasingly (though they stop if the button labeled <kbd>X Hide results</kbd> is clicked).

Does the `currentUser` and `posts` change other than when the `created` lifecycle hook is called?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    base_url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
    uid: 1,
    currentUser: null,
    userData: null,
    users: [],
    posts: []
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActiveUser(user) {
      this.uid = user.id;
    },
    getUsers() {
      axios
        .get(`${this.base_url}/users`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
    getCurrentUser() {
      axios
        .get(`${this.base_url}/users/${this.uid}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.currentUser = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
    getPosts() {
      axios
        .get(`${this.base_url}/posts?userId=${this.uid}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.posts = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.getCurrentUser();
    this.getPosts();
  },
  watch: {
    currentUser() {
      console.log('watch current user - calling getCurrentUser()');
      this.getCurrentUser();
    },
    posts() {
      console.log('watch current posts - calling getPosts()');
      this.getPosts();
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize(value) {
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    },
    titlecase(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|[\s-/])\w/g, function(match) {
        return match.toUpperCase();
      });
    },
    lowercase(value) {
      return value.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.logo {
  width: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-item {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.post-grid {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.post-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.post-title {
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

.short-desc {
  text-align: justify;
}


/* User Info */

.table.user-info {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.table.user-info>tbody>tr:first-child>td {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.table.user-info td {
  padding: 6px !important;
}

.table.user-info tr td:first-child {
  font-weight: 500;
  width: 32% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand p-0" href="#">
      <img src="https://www.pngrepo.com/png/303293/180/bootstrap-4-logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler d-md-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-md  w-100">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-md collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Dropdown -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Authors</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" v-if="users">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" @click="toggleActiveUser(user)">{{user.name}}</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="h4 mt-3">Posts by {{currentUser?.name}}</h1>

    <div v-if="currentUser != null">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
      More about this author
    </button>
    </div>

    <div class="row post-grid" v-if="posts">
      <div class="col-sm-6 post" v-for="post in posts">
        <div class="post-container">
          <h2 class="display-4 post-title">{{post.title | titlecase}}</h2>
          <div class="short-desc">
            {{post.body | capitalize}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div v-if="currentUser != null" class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{currentUser?.name}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="table user-info">
            <tr>
              <td>Lives in</td>
              <td>{{currentUser?.address.city}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Address</td>
              <td>{{currentUser?.address.street}}, {{currentUser?.address.suite}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Zipcode</td>
              <td>{{currentUser?.address.zipcode}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Email</td>
              <td>
                <a href="mailto:{{currentUser?.email | lowercase}}">{{currentUser?.email | lowercase}}</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Other comments

### Style nit-pick - filter method names

I noticed there are filters like `titlecase` and `lowercase` which deviate from the camelCase style. I would prefer those be `lowerCase` and `titleCase` but that's just my opinion and you are free to ignore it.

Comment: "This typically leads to an infinite loop". How would you fix it?

Comment: That depends on what would be required to “fix” it. When should it request new data? Should new data be requested when the value (e.g. of `posts`, `currentUser`) is something [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) like `null`/`undefined` Or even `{}`/`[]`? If so the watch callbacks can accept the new value as the first parameter (and old value as second parameter if needed) and use those accordingly

Comment: What would your choice be? In other words, how would you (choose to) do it?

Comment: Unless someone can convince me that the `watch` callbacks are essential I’d remove those - and perhaps add code to handle the case where loading of the posts and current user doesn’t load an expected value - e.g. retry if acceptable up to a limit like 5 retries